# Is doing something else in setter methods considered having side effects?

Tags: java, oop

Recently I have read some articles saying that methods having side effects is not good. So I just want to ask if my implementation here can be categorized as having side effect.

Suppose I have a `SecurityGuard` which checks to see if he should allow a customer to go to the club or not.

The `SecurityGuard` either has only list of validNames or list of invalidNames, not both.

- if the `SecurityGuard` has only validNames, he only allows customer whose name on the list.
- if the `SecurityGuard` has only invalidNames, he only allows customer whose name NOT on the list.
- if the `SecurityGuard` has no lists at all, he allows everyone.

So to enforce the logic, on setter of each list, I reset the other list if the new list has value.

```
class SecurityGaurd {
    private List<String> validNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> invalidNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setValidNames(List<String> newValidNames) {
        this.validNames = new ArrayList<>(newValidNames);
        // empty the invalidNames if newValidNames has values
        if (!this.validNames.isEmpty()) {
            this.invalidNames = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public void setInvalidNames(List<String> newInvalidNames) {
        this.invalidNames = new ArrayList<>(newInvalidNames);
        // empty the validNames if newInvalidNames has values
        if (!this.invalidNames.isEmpty()) {
            this.validNames = new ArrayList<>(); //empty the validNames
        }
    }


    public boolean allowCustomerToPass(String customerName) {
        if (!validNames.isEmpty()) {
            return validNames.contains(customerName);
        }
        return !invalidNames.contains(customerName);
    }
}
```

So here you can see the setter methods have an implicit action, it resets the other list.

The question is what I'm doing here could be considered having a side effect? Is it bad enough so that we have to change it? And if yes, how can I improve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems fine, should not be a problem. That's what setters() are for!

Comment: I don't think so, your conditions are well defined. So long as you can support it with documentation for people who might trying to set both methods.  The only thing you could do differently is throw an `IllegalStateException` if the developer tries to set one of the lists while the other exists.

Comment: Anyway, I would check for null in the setters. Also, creating a new Arraylist that "wraps" the original it's a good practice. In this blog you can see a very good explanation, http://blog.codejava.net/nam/implement-getters-and-setters-for-collection-type/

Comment: @psabbate: I aimed to make the code as simple as possible so I omitted null check here. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that the guard just had one `SetAdmissionPolicy` which accepted a reference to an `AdmissionPolicy` defined:

```
interface AdmissionPolicy {
    boolean isAcceptable(String customerName) {
}
```

and set the guard's `admissionPolicy` field to the passed-in reference.  The guard's own `allowCustomerToPass` method simply called `admissionPolicy.isAcceptable(customerName);`.

Given the above definitions, one can imagine three classes that implement `AdmissionPolicy`: one would accept a list in its constructor, and `isAcceptable` would return true for everyone on the list, another would also accept a list in its constructor, but its `isAcceptable` would return true only for people *not* on the list.  A third would simply return true unconditionally.  If the club needs to close occasionally, one might also have a fourth implementation that returned false unconditionally.

Viewed in such a way, `setInvalidNames` and `setValidNames` could both be implemented as:

```
public void setAdmissionPolicyAdmitOnly(List<String> newValidNames) {
    admissionPolicy = new AdmitOnlyPolicy(newValidNames);
}

public void setAdmissionPolicyAdmitAllBut(List<String> newInvalidNames) {
    admissionPolicy = new AdmitAllButPolicy(newInvalidNames);
}
```

With such an implementation, it would be clear that each method was only "setting" one thing; such an implementation is how I would expect a class such as yours to behave.

The behavior of your class as described, however, I would regard as dubious at best.  The issue isn't so much that adding admitted items clears out the rejected items, but rather that the behavior when a passed-in list is empty depends upon the earlier state in a rather bizarre fashion.  It's hardly intuitive that if everyone but Fred is allowed access, calling setValidNames to nothing should have no effect, but if it's set to only allow George access that same call should grant access to everyone.  Further, while it would not be unexpected that `setValidNames` would remove from `invalidNames` anyone who was included in the valid-names list nor vice versa, given the way the functions are named, the fact that setting one list removes *everyone* from the other list is somewhat unexpected (the different behavior with empty lists makes it especially so).

Comment: Your solution is very nice. I didn't expect to receive such a nice answer at this time. Thanks!

Comment: @Genzer: Glad it was helpful.  One other possible change would be to use type `HashSet<String>` internally rather than `List<String>`.  You could also use `Collection<String>` as your parameter type rather than `List<String>` (any class that implements `List<>` also implements `Collection<>`), which would allow your methods to accept a `HashSet<String>` as well as `List<String>`.

Comment: Actually, the point of my question is whether doing something like this is considered a side-effect. The code is just for example. But with your suggested solution, it can eliminate the side-effect. I actually can remove all the `setXXXName` and just provide `setAdmissionPolicy`.

Comment: @Genzer: My preferred design is to, when practical, define an object's characteristics in terms of independent traits which can be specified independently with defined characteristics for all combinations, and only include "set" methods for those; for other traits, use a different term.  For example, if a control's horizontal boundaries are defined in terms of `Left` and `Width`, it may have a `getRight` method, but rather than `setRight` it should have `moveToSetRight` and `resizeToSetRight`.  The fact that `setLeft` and `setWidth` change the value reported by `getRight`...

Comment: ...would be more a "consequence" than a side-effect; the fact that `moveToSetRight` would affect `Left` would be *direct* effect.  Even though that's my preferred design, however, I would not find it overly surprising if, in a library that defined control bounds in terms of `Left` and `Right`, setting a control's `Right` to a value below its left pushed the left edge correspondingly.  I wouldn't *like* such a design, but wouldn't find it astonishing [I'd prefer to instead have defined behavior for when `Left` is to the left of `Right`, so they could be set independently].

Comment: @Genzer: If the clearing of the "opposite" trait were unconditional, I would view the behavior of your code as somewhat analogous to a `ThermometerDisplay` control which included `setTemperatureFahrenheit` and `setTemperatureCelcius` methods, each of which actually set two or three characteristics: (`isCelcius`, and either `numericTemperature` or both `temperatureFahrenheit` and `temperatureCelcius`).  It might be possible for the control to only keep the Celcius temperature, but if code calls `setFahrenheit(12.375)` and then calls `getFahrenheight`, it should get the exact value set.

Answer (score 6):

Well, setters themselves have side effects (A value in that instance is left modified after the function ends). So, no, I wouldn't consider it something bad that needs to be changed.

Comment: So under which conditions, we can consider a method having side effects?

Answer (score 1):

It does not have any side effect although , its assumed by developers that getters and setters may not have any underlying code apart from getting and setting the variable. Hence when another developer tries to maintain the code , he would probably overlook at your code of the Bean and do the same checks as done by you in the setters - Possible Boiler Plate code as you would call it

Comment: Thanks! Could give some thought what I should do to avoid such boiler plate code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd not consider it as a side effect. You are maintaining the underlying assumptions of your object. I'm not sure it's the best design, but it's certainly a working one.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I don't think changing the other linkedlist will be a side affect, since the scope is within this class.

However, based on your description, maybe it is better design to have one linkedList (called nameList) and a boolean (isValid) that differentiate between a whitelist and a blacklist. This way it is clear that only one type of list be filled at any time.

Comment: Thanks! But I think your solution would make the code more complicated though. P.s: I actually used `ArrayList` in the example :D

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OK. E.g. if you want your class to be immutable the best place to do it is setter:

```
public void setNames(List<String> names) {
       this.names = names == null ? Collections.emptyList() : Collections.unmodifiableList(names);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I only expose setters here, so making unmodifiableList is not neccesary. But thanks for pointing out I should return a defensive copy of the list to maintain the constraint if I do expose getters.

Comment: The point is that when you simply copy a reference to a list in setter, the list can be modified outside the class since the reference to the list is exposed